# How would you markup a building plan/map using semantic HTML?

Tags: html, markup, semantics

The building (a museum) has 7 levels (+3 to -3), each divided into different rooms/areas. Hovering over an area will reveal a popup describing that area.

I'm looking for some markup that will accurately represent the 7 levels and their areas.
The plan should make sense and be 'navigable' without any CSS/JS.

Edit: Some clarification, the markup only has to represent the 'semantic structure' of the building, not the spatial layout (CSS will add in the layout and graphics).

Answer (score 2):

Smells like a nested, unordered list to me.

Comment: I was thinking definition lists?

Comment: It varies, between 2-6 rooms per floor

Comment: I don't think definition lists are meant to be nested; semantically they are a flat list of name/value pairs. A nested unordered list is a good fit for this.

Comment: It is true that definition lists shouldn't be nested?

Comment: I posted the definition list question over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389086

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for SVG? ([Sample Adobe Building in San Jose](http://www.adobe.com/svg/demos/vbs/html/frameset.html))

I realize that this does use JavaScript, but if you have 7 floors * 10+ rooms? this would get rather hairy with pure CSS.  You could use some `<ul>` elements to make nested levels of rooms, but if the building is this big, I don't think the list (even if rendered as blocks) would be meaningful to view.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [microformats](http://microformats.org/wiki/Main_Page), specifically the [XOXO Microformat](http://microformats.org/wiki/XOXO).

Comment: Thanks. What are the advantages of using XOXO, it wasn't made clear on the wiki page?

Answer (score 1):

Using HTML5 (but shouldn't make a big difference if you'd like to use HTML 4.01):

If you want to represent the building with images, you can use an [Image Map](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/image-maps.html#image-maps), consisting of [`map`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-map-element.html#the-map-element) and [`area`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-area-element.html#the-area-element). The `area` (`href` attribute) could link to a page containing the detailed description of the room. The `alt` attribute could contain a short description of the room, like "Strawberry room (level 4)".

If the markup is more like a text-alternative (for example, if you'd use `object`, `canvas` or something like that), I would go with a heading structure:

```
<section>
 <h1>The building</h1>

 <section id="level-1">
  <h1>Level 1</h1>

   <section id="level-1-room-1">
    <h1>Room 1</h1>
    <p>description of room 1</p>
   </section>

   <section id="level-1-room-2">
    <h1>Room 2</h1>
    <p>description of room 2</p>
   </section>

 </section> <!-- #level-1 -->

 <section id="level-2">
  <h1>Level 2</h1>

   <section id="level-2-room-1">
    <h1>Room 1</h1>
    <p>description of room 1</p>
   </section>

   <section id="level-2-room-2">
    <h1>Room 2</h1>
    <p>description of room 2</p>
   </section>

 </section> <!-- #level-2 -->

</section>
```

(for HTML 4.01, you would use `div` instead of `section` and adjust the heading level accordingly)