# Is it correct to nest HTML definition lists (<dl>)?

Tags: html, markup, semantics

Is it semantically correct to nest definition lists, or should they simply be a 'flat list of name/value pairs'.

[The specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.1) don't seem to forbid it.

Further to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388843/).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Well the spec seems to allow it, provided that only the `<dd>` contains nested lists. The spec states that a `<dt>` is an inline element, so it can't contain a nested list. A `<dd>` is a block element, so an inner list inside one of these is fine.

Comment: Firefox 48 and IE9 handle direct nesting of a DL as a child of a DL just fine. Google Chrome renders it wrong: no indentation; everything flush left. If you wrap the nested DL with a DD tag, nothing changes in the way it is rendered by IE or FF. On Chrome, the indentation appears, but there is an ugly extra blank vertical space between the top of the nested list and the previous item in the enclosing list.

Comment: However, the react compiler throws an error for invalid dom nesting:`<dd> cannot appear as a descendant of <dd>`.

Answer (score 4):

Sure. There's nothing wrong with nested `DL`s. You can semantically have "subdefinitions."

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

It's true that DefLists are intended to represent Keys and Values, but the multiplicity on those isn't 1 it's 1+. If that complexity is allowed, and bearing in mind that dt's are inline, I see no semantic problem with representing defining something in terms of a tree of other things.

Answer (score -2):

I solved that by replacing nested definition lists by unordered or ordered list, eg.

```
<dl>
  <dd>Black hot drink</dd>
  <ul>
    <dd>White cold drink</dd>
    <ol>
      <dd>Red sweet drink</dd>
    </ol>
  </ul>
</dl>
```

Answer (score -7):

If it works in all the browsers, then do it.

I know this might be controversial, and a lot of people will probably tell you it isn't the way it's supposed to be used. The unwritten rules of webdesign, like using lists for almost anything, are just what people have decided to do. There is no reason why you should be using float (which purpose is to float an image inside a block of text) to layout every little detail on a website. But if you try to use tables you are an apparently an idiot from the pre-bubble era, and you have no idea how to design.

So, do what you want to do, and don't make things more complicated just to fix the problem.

Comment: Comparing Table design vs float use is a bit unfair, whenever you extract **data** from an HTML file, you actually determine the meaning of data using the provided elements while CSS is purely a presentation behavior, that's the semantic web is about...